# Unable to import NPM library in stackblitz

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, stackblitz

Hi I am trying to recreate an Angular example online But unable to see my import my [Tabulator Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tabulator-tables)  in stackblitz

getting error on import in hello component

```
import Tabulator from 'tabulator-tables';
```

works perfectly fine in my IDE, is there any alternative to stackblitz  or fix for this

Error is reproducible in the link below hello component
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckujf9

[image]

Comment: worked here, 4.2.5 installed

Comment: oh, it's not working, sorry, but in a javascript project it's working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zlq4zq

Comment: https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/229#issuecomment-378288718 try to use it in the stackblitz project, maybe it's just a UI bug

Comment: @Gaspar that was a bug thanks it works now

Comment: I will answer it for newcomers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some modules is not dressed like your IDE, but the modules is present in the in internal node_modules package. Like a stackblitz member say in this post there is a UI Bug lying that could not load the module.